# What is the value of $I=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 {{1 + nx^2}\over{(1 + x^2)^n}} \log(2 + \cos(x/n))\,dx.$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, asymptotics

Find the integral $I$.....it looks like a good problem which I was not able to solve ....please help...

$$I=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 {{1 + nx^2}\over{(1 + x^2)^n}} \log(2 + \cos(x/n))\,dx.$$

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: the leading order as $n\rightarrow\infty$ is given by $I_n\sim\frac{3\log(3)\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: No I am not familiar with dominated convergence sequence.......

Comment: Yes I am familiar with uniform convergence.....

Comment: @tired Perhaps you should post a solution.  It would be instructive to present the development of the leading term in the asymptotic series.  -Mark

Comment: Limit and integral can replace positions, since $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $0$. You can show that $0\leq sup_{x} |f_n(x)|\leq \frac{n}{(2-\frac{1}{n})^n}\log3$ and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty} sup_{x} |f_n(x)-0|=0$.

Comment: @Dr.MV done! :-)

Comment: @alans $f_n(x)$ does not uniformly converge to $0$.  At $x=0$ $f_n(x)=\log(3)$ for all $n$.  Therefore, the limit function is discontinuous.

Comment: @Dr. MV Uh, my mistake. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 6):

By Bernoullis inequality, we have $\frac{1+nx^2}{(1+x^2)^n}\leq 1$.

Also, $\cos{t}\leq 1$.

Therefore, $$|f_n(x)|=\left|{{1 + nx^2}\over{(1 + x^2)^n}} \log(2 + \cos(x/n))\right|\leq\log{3}=g(x)$$

Now, by [DCT](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Dominated_convergence_theorem), we have
$I=0$.

Comment: (+1) for the nice answer and to remove the silly downvote

Answer (score 6):

The main contributions to the integral will be from the interval $[0,1/\sqrt{n}]$. In this region $ \cos(x/n)\approx 1$ and therefore

$$
I_n\sim\log(3)\int_0^{1/\sqrt{n}}dx e^{-n\log(1+x^2)}(1+nx^2)\sim\log(3)\int_0^{1/\sqrt{n}}dx e^{-n x^2}(1+nx^2)
$$

because we are only introducing an exponentially small error by pushing the limits of integration up to infinity (Laplace method) we get

> $$
> I_n\sim\log(3)\int_0^{\infty}dx e^{-n x^2}(1+nx^2)=\log(3)\frac{3\sqrt{\pi}}{4\sqrt{n}}
> $$

and the limit is $0$.

Note that  it is important to keep $1$ as well as $nx^2$ in the integrand because their contributions turn out to be of the same order!

Comment: The remarks made [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1866348/) apply here, mutatis mutandis.

Answer (score 6):

Note that after enforcing the substitution $x\to x/\sqrt{n}$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^1 \frac{1+nx^2}{(1+x^2)^n}\log\left(2+\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\right)\,dx\right|&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_0^\sqrt{n} \frac{1+x^2}{(1+x^2/n)^n}\log\left(2+\cos\left(\frac{x}{n^{3/2}}\right)\right)\,dx\\\\
&\le \frac{\log(3)}{\sqrt{n}} \int_0^\infty \frac{1+x^2}{\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n}\right)^n}\,dx \tag 1\\\\
&\le \frac{\log(3)}{\sqrt{n}} \int_0^\infty \frac{1+x^2}{\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^2}\,dx \tag 2\\\\
&=\frac{\log(3)}{\sqrt{n}}\,\left(\frac{3\sqrt{2}\pi}{4}\right)\tag 3
\end{align}$$

where we used the fact that $\left(1+\frac {x^2}n\right)^n\ge \left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^2$ for $n\ge2$ in going from $(1)$ to $(2)$.

The right-hand side of $(3)$ clearly approaches zero as $n\to \infty$.  Therefore, the squeeze theorem guarantees that the integral of interest approaches zero also. And we are done!

Comment: @tired Not nearly as good as yours, which actually develops the leading term of the asymptotic expansion.  But thank you!

Comment: great solution.....atleast for me (a high school student.........)

Comment: @Viku Thank you!  Much appreciated.