# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} n \int_0^1 (\cos x - \sin x)^n dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find:
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \int_0^1 (\cos x - \sin x)^n dx$$

This is one of the problems i have to solve so that i could join college. I tried using integration by parts, i tried using notations but nothing works. If someone could please help me i would deeply appreciate it. ! thanks in advance ! I know the answer to the limit is 1. But i need help proving it.

Comment: L'hopitals may help.

Comment: hmm, you mean to use L'hospitals like this ?  I transform that n into 1/n and i put it under the integral then i apply L'hospital? @AhmedS.Attaalla
https://gyazo.com/6576519a9581adab111bb180e67eac83 like this?

Comment: At first glance it seemed to be a standard L'hopital rule problem but now I'm not sure. What exact section are you working so we can get an idea of what method is involved? @Razvan

Comment: Im not sure to what do you reffer by "section". I just finished highschool and im trying to go to university. I studied mathematics-informatics in school. Im not sure i understood your question though. @AhmedS.Attaalla

Comment: Okay just don't mind what I've said. @Razvan

Comment: Thank you for trying tho ! all help is welcomed !

Answer (score 5):

Write the integrand as  $(\cos(x)-\sin(x))^n=e^{n\log(\cos(x)-\sin(x))}$. Looking at a [few plots](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%5B(cosx-sinx),(cosx-sinx)%5E10,(cosx-sinx)%5E(100),%7Bx,0,1%7D%5D) it becomes immediatly clear the integral will be dominated by a small region around the origin with width $\epsilon\sim1/n$ as $n \rightarrow\infty$. The more formal reason for that is, that the exponent is nearly zero around the origin

$$
I_n=\int_0^1(\cos(x)-\sin(x))^n\sim \int_0^{\epsilon}e^{n\log(\cos(x)-\sin(x))}
$$

Taylor expansion of the exponent yields

$$
I_n\sim\int_0^{\epsilon}e^{-x n}
$$

by pushing $\epsilon$ to infinity we introduce only an exponentially small error so

$$
I_n \sim\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x n}=\frac{1}{n}
$$

which yields

> $$
> \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n I_n=1
> $$

Comment: Thank you for your help kind sir, may the god of math always be by your side !

Comment: thanks, but this is not necessary anymore...i finished my phd in theoretical physics yesterday ;)

Comment: No wonder you know how to use the Taylor series..this is the first time i hear about them to be honest. Thank you again !

Comment: taylor series means that to develop a function in a power series around a specific point. maybe it would be best to first consult wikipedia: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Comment: Your answer has some problem since $\log(\cos x-\sin x)$ does not make sense when $x\in[\pi/4,1]$.

Comment: @xpaul because for my argument to be valid, $\log$ needs only to be well defined in a region of size $x\sim1/n$ around the origin, which is indeed the case

Comment: @tired, your proof is not rigorous enough.

Comment: @tired, I did not downvote your answer.

Comment: @xpaul i was not supposing that...:). point is, this answer shall show the general way how to get a result by asymototic estimates. if the op wishes more rigour he is encouraged to fill in the steps himself and to ask if something is unclear. But, nevertheless, where exactly you wanna see more rigour?

Comment: I have been amazed by the fact that $\int (\cos(x)-\sin(x))^n\,dx$ has a "rather simple" expression.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici "I have been amazed by the fact that ∫(cos(x)−sin(x))ndx has a "rather simple" expression" Hmm, has it? Not that I know. Would you be confusing asymptotics when $n\to\infty$ with exact formulas for some given $n$?

Comment: To turn this post into a mathematical answer, one could mention that this is a simple case of [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace's_method) and one should state precisely the general theorem one wishes to apply and check that its hypotheses hold in the present case. In particular, the fact that the function $\cos x-\sin x$ has a single maximum at $x=0$ on the interval $[0,1]$ and its behaviour near $x=0$ should be made explicit.

Comment: @Did my post outlines the procedure to obtain the given limit and also presents the correct results. i don't think it is my job here to fill in all the steps to make this completly rigorous . This is something the op might want to do if it seems necessary (and he can also ask politily if he needs help with that).

Comment: @tired Congratulations for your degree. I got one at UCSD in 1983. A long time ago !!!.

Answer (score 2):

The following common inequalities suffice here:
$
\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$

- $1+x+\lfrac12 x^2 \le \exp(x) \le 1 + x + x^2$ for every real $x \in [0,\ln(2)]$.
- $1 - \lfrac12 x^2 \le \cos(x) \le 1 - \lfrac12 x^2 + \lfrac1{24} x^4$ for every real $x$.
- $x - \lfrac16 x^3 \le \sin(x) \le x$ for every real $x \ge 0$.

They can be proven elementarily by recursively comparing derivatives.

---

As $n \to \infty$:

Let $r = n^{2/3}$.

Given any $x \in [0,\lfrac1r]$:

$\cos(x) - \sin(x) \le 1 - x + \lfrac16 x^3 \le \exp(-x)$.

$\cos(x) - \sin(x) \ge 1 - x - \lfrac12 x^2 \ge \exp(-x-2x^2)$ since $x \to 0$.

Thus $(\cos(x)-\sin(x))^n \in \exp(-x) ^ n \cdot [\exp(-\frac{2}{r^2}),1]^n$.

Thus ${\displaystyle\int}_0^{\lfrac1r} n ( \cos(x) - \sin(x) )^n\ dx \in [\exp(-\frac{2n}{r^2}),1] \cdot {\displaystyle\int}_0^{\lfrac1r} n \exp(-nx)\ dx$.

Also ${\displaystyle\int}_0^{\lfrac1r} n \exp(-nx)\ dx = 1 - \exp(-\lfrac{n}{r}) \to 1$.

Given any $x \in [\lfrac1r,1]$:

$\cos(x) - \sin(x) \le 1 - x - x^2 ( \lfrac12 - \lfrac16 x - \lfrac1{24} x^2 ) \le 1 - \lfrac1r$.

$\cos(x) - \sin(x) \ge 1 - x - \lfrac12 x^2 \ge -\frac12$.

Thus $| n ( \cos(x) - \sin(x) )^n | \le n ( 1 - \lfrac1r )^n \to 0$.

Thus ${\displaystyle\int}_{\lfrac1r}^1 n ( \cos(x) - \sin(x) )^n\ dx \to 0$.

Therefore ${\displaystyle\int}_0^1 n ( \cos(x) - \sin(x) )^n\ dx \to 1$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: You may be interested in my answer. I cut the integral into two pieces at $n^{-2/3}$ so that both parts can be easily proven to converge, rigorously.