# Find $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(n \int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0 (\cos(x)-\sin(x))^n \right)$

Tags: limits

> > Find $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \left(n \int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0 (\cos(x)-\sin(x))^n \right)$$

I've managed to prove that the limit is in $(0,1]$ and I believe it is $1$ but I don't know how to prove it. Could you help me?

Comment: Are you sure it's in (0,1]? $n-n^2$ is negative, but the integral is positive. How can the limit of a sequence of negative terms be positive?

Comment: I think that $n-n^2$ should be just $n$.

Comment: You perhaps have a typo. The correct question is http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2121035/72031

Comment: Oh, it was already answered with more precision in the link by Paramanand Singh.

Comment: @i707107: no worry you still get a +1 for your efforts from my side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $\cos x = \sin(\pi/2 - x)$ and $\sin A - \sin B = 2\cos (\frac{A+B}2)\sin (\frac{A-B}2)$, we have
$$
\cos x - \sin x = \sqrt 2 \sin(\frac{\pi}4 - x).$$
From this, we have 
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}4} (\cos x - \sin x)^n dx = 2^{n/2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}4} \sin^n (\frac{\pi}4 - x) dx= 2^{n/2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}4} \sin^n x dx := 2^{n/2} I_n . 
$$
Let $J_n = n 2^{n/2} I_n$. Then by the reduction formula, we have
$$
J_n = -1 + \frac{2(n-1)}{n-2}J_{n-2}.
$$
Then 
$$
J_n-1 = \frac 2{n-2} + 2(1+\frac 1{n-2} ) (J_{n-2} -1) .
$$
It is easy to check that $J_n$ is bounded, so   $J_n-1$ is also bounded. 
Taking $\limsup$ on the right, we have for $\alpha = \limsup (J_n-1)$, 
$$
\alpha\geq 2\alpha.
$$
Then take $\limsup$ on the left, we have 
$$
\alpha \leq 2\alpha.
$$
Thus, $\alpha = 2\alpha = 0$. Similarly for $\liminf$, we obtain $\liminf (J_n-1) = 0$. 
Therefore $\lim J_n = 1$.

This shows that 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n \int_0^{\frac{\pi}4} (\cos x - \sin x )^n  dx = 1.
$$